# calling a form from require/include PHP file give white screen of death

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am using Xampp, VSCode, and Chrome.

My index.php file that has two tools within it.

Tool 1 has 5 forms that are used to input data. There is a math#.php file associated with each form and they are the "action" for each form. (math1.php, math2.php etc). The user input values are used to perform calculations. In each math.php, a call to my database.php (I "require" this file) file is made, which is needed to complete the calculation. At the end of each math.php file there is a "require index.php" to ensure that the user can fill out the next form since going to a math#.php file is technically a different page. There is a HTML table in index.php that displays the values entered from the user, and the calculated output.

So for example, the user will fill out form 1 in index.php and submit. Calculations are performed in math1.php. and the now populated variables are shown in the table. The user will then fill out  form 2 and click submit. Math2.php is performed and "require index.php" is added at the end. The calculations and values produce build off each other so that the user has a fully filled out table. It is clunky, but I am passing the variables as hidden through each form so that the output table in index.php is populated accordingly.

```
Tool 1 works standalone.
```

Tool 2 is composed of a form located at the bottom of index.php. The user inputs some values and calls my database to populate a table below it.

```
Tool 2 works standalone.
```

My issue is that when I fill out any of the forms in tool 1 and click submit, then fill out the for for tool 2 and click submit, I get a blank white screen. I can provide any further details if needed. I have read many post about the white screen of death, but none of the solutions I have seen yet have provided a solution in my case.

Comment: do you have errors turned on? `ini_set("display_errors","On"); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: I have added those lines and no errors are produced on screen and none in the logs that I am seeing.

Comment: I added them at the top of index.php

Comment: Can't say much without seeing the code. Note you can add only the relevant part of your code to your question.

Comment: I understand. Is there a particular part of the process you think would be most useful? I will also note that I added break points toward the top of both index.php and math1.php and after I performed tool 1's first calc, the submit on tool 2 did not hit any break points and displayed the white screen. I am considering that maybe I am using too much memory in XAMPP or one of the requires is involved with the error. if there is a particular piece of this process you'd like to see I will post